# How to draw horizontal lines

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to draw horizontal lines where it's -8%, -15%, -21%, and -35% of the previous high.

I managed to get the highest plot, but I can't seem to get the horizontal lines drawn with the new complexity of pinescript-v5

Instead of V5, I've changed it to V3. I roughly got the idea but I would like to base the highest as float instead of a series

This is my current script:

```
//@version=3
study(title="The Adam Khoo Magic", overlay=true)

//Input options
highlength = input(title="High Length", defval=20, type=integer)

//calculate values
highhighs = highest(high, length=highlength)

minuseight = highhighs*0.92
minusfifteen = highhighs*0.85
minustwentyone = highhighs*0.79
minusthirtyfive = highhighs*0.65

p8 = plot(minuseight, title="-8%", color=olive, linewidth=2, style=line)
p15 = plot(minusfifteen, title="-15%", color=purple, linewidth=2, style=line)
p21 = plot(minustwentyone, title="-21%", color=navy, linewidth=2, style=line)
p35 = plot(minusthirtyfive, title="-35%", color=black, linewidth=2, style=line)

fill(p8, p15, color=red)
fill(p15, p21, color=blue)
fill(p21, p35, color=green)

//plot values on the chart
plot(series=highhighs, color=green, linewidth=1)
plot(minuseight, title="-8%", color=olive, linewidth=2, style=line)
plot(minusfifteen, title="-15%", color=purple, linewidth=2, style=line)
plot(minustwentyone, title="-21%", color=navy, linewidth=2, style=line)
plot(minusthirtyfive, title="-35%", color=black, linewidth=2, style=line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply the nature of the hline function. It cannot draw from a series of data. The second issue is that you cannot convert a series into a single data point in such a way to resolve the issue as far as the hline function goes.

There is however a solution to this, and it's to instead use custom `line`s.
Note I am using pinescript v5 because I am more familiar with it.

First, we draw the fill color, since this function *is* able to use a series of data.

```js
//@version=5
indicator(title="The Adam Khoo Magic", overlay=true)

//Input options

highlength = input.int(20, "High Length")

//color fill

highhighs = ta.highest(high, highlength)

p8 = plot(highhighs*0.92, display=display.none, editable=false)
p15 = plot(highhighs*0.85, display=display.none, editable=false)
p21 = plot(highhighs*0.79, display=display.none, editable=false)
p35 = plot(highhighs*0.65, display=display.none, editable=false)

fill(p8, p15, color=color.new(color.red, 90))
fill(p15, p21, color=color.new(color.blue, 90))
fill(p21, p35, color=color.new(color.green, 90))
```

This will draw the fill colors for you but will avoid drawing the series because of the `display=display.none` parameter. Now the more complex part; drawing the horizontal lines between them.

To do this, we start by creating empty line variables, importantly using the `var` keyword before the `line` keyword.

```js
//horizontal lines

var line minuseight = na
var line minusfifteen = na
var line minustwentyone = na
var line minusthirtyfive = na
```

Without the `var` keyword, every update of the chart data will mess with our `line` variables in ways we don't want.

Next, we check for the specific conditions in which we want to update the line variables with the appropriate position data, using if statements.

```js
if not barstate.isconfirmed or (barstate.isrealtime and barstate.islast and not barstate.isconfirmed)
    minuseight := line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=highhighs*0.92, x2=bar_index, y2=highhighs*0.92, width=1, extend=extend.both)
    minusfifteen := line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=highhighs*0.85, x2=bar_index, y2=highhighs*0.85, width=1, extend=extend.both)
    minustwentyone := line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=highhighs*0.79, x2=bar_index, y2=highhighs*0.79, width=1, extend=extend.both)
    minusthirtyfive := line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=highhighs*0.65, x2=bar_index, y2=highhighs*0.65, width=1, extend=extend.both)
    
    line.set_color(id=minuseight, color=color.white)
    line.set_style(id=minuseight, style=line.style_solid)
    
    line.set_color(id=minusfifteen, color=color.white)
    line.set_style(id=minusfifteen, style=line.style_solid)
    
    line.set_color(id=minustwentyone, color=color.white)
    line.set_style(id=minustwentyone, style=line.style_solid)
    
    line.set_color(id=minusthirtyfive, color=color.white)
    line.set_style(id=minusthirtyfive, style=line.style_solid)
```

Lastly, we delete the lines every time a bar closes:

```js
if barstate.isconfirmed
    line.delete(id=minuseight)
    line.delete(id=minusfifteen)
    line.delete(id=minustwentyone)
    line.delete(id=minusthirtyfive)

// end of script here
```

Put all that together in that order and the code you presented will work and will include the dynamic horizontal lines you wanted!

*Note, the reason we use the series to draw the fill colors instead of the dynamic horizontal lines is because of similar technical reasons to your original issue; the fill function cannot use line variables as input.*

[image: result of my code]

Comment: That certainly shows how to draw a straight line thanks!
I found a workaround by plotting by wavy lines with a for...loop

maxhigh = for i = 1 to highlength by 1
    maxhigh = 0
    if highesthights[i] > maxhigh
        maxhigh = highesthights[i]
        maxhigh